# Trouble finding sum of odd integers cubed

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Tried several times yet still didnt manage to find my mistake: here is my program. i need to find the odd numbers from 1 and integer x and find the sum of them cubed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x;
  int i = 1;
  int result;
  cout <<" Enter the value for n" << endl;
  cin >> x;

  while (i >x)
  if (i%2 == 0) {}

  else {

    result += pow(i,3);
    i++;
  }

  cout << "The sum of odd integers cubes from " << i << " to " << x << "= " << result << endl;



  return 0;

}
```

Comment: First off, you should avoid `using namespace std`, second, take a look around the `while(i > x)` you seem to be missing something there.

Comment: Maybe to get the odd integers you could consider a `for()` loop starting at 1 and incrementing by 2.  e.g.:  `for (i=1; i<x; i+=2)` then you should only have odd numbers for `i`.

Comment: BTW, the `pow` function is floating point and returns floating point.  Multiplication is more efficients e.g. `i * i * i`.

Comment: You could skip the empty code in your `if` by negating the condition, e.g. `if ((i%2) != 0) { result = i * i * i; ++i}`

Answer (score 2):

Minimally, you should change the compare in `while`
from
  `while (i > n)`
to
  `while (i <= n)`

There a many numbers where `i` will be greater than the number entered, `n`.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't add in your curly brackets for the while loop.

```
while (i > x)
if (i%2 == 0) {}
```

needs to be:

```
 while (i > x){

 if (i % 2 == 0) {}

 }
```

Plus what are you doing inside of that if statement?  You should decrement x, to find if each number is odd.

Plus, your program ends early because i is 1 and if the user enters a number above 1, your while loop won't even run.  You're telling the while loop to run ONLY when i is larger than x.  Try changing it to less than:

from:

```
 while (i > x){
```

to:

```
 while (i < x){
```

Plus you're not doing anything with x.  You want to decrement x, not add i.  Although, I would recommend using a do-while loop. ( a dowhile loop does one iteration first before incrementation)

```
do{
if (x % 2 == 0) { // if the remainder of x/2 is 0, do this 
     x--;
     cout << "Equal: " << x << endl;
}
if(x % 2 != 0) { //if the remainder of x/2 is not 0, do this.  

   temp = pow(x,3); 
   //you don't want to take the power of the added sum, 
   //you were taking the power 3 of x which was being added to.
   //you want to add the sums of each power.  So here we have temp, a 
   //temporary variable to store your addends.
   result = result + temp;
   cout << "Not equal, temp:" << temp <<endl;
   cout << "Result: "<< result << endl;
   x--;  //you didn't have a decrement, you need to bring x eventually down to i if you want the loop to end, or even look through all of the numbers
   }
}
while (i < x);
//You have to have this semi colon here for the compiler to know its a do-while.
 cout << "The sum of odd integers cubes from " << i << " to " << userVar 
 << " = " << result << endl;

 return 0;
 }
```

note:  if-else statements are for flow control, its like true and false, one or the other, so that your data will flow *somewhere*.  I used two if statements because I want to have complete control over the flow.

note2:  It's ok to use:

```
 using namespace std;
```

at first, but eventually you want to start learning what library each command is using.  When you get into more complex programming, you start using commands from different libraries than the standard one.

Comment: Please format your answer correctly. Also, you should never encourage the use of `using namespace std`. Better to break the evil habit now instead of later down the road.

Comment: why are they considered a bad habit? i am new to programming and wondering

Comment: Thanks alot for the helpful repsone

Comment: They're considered a bad habit because later on in programming you have to reference a different library that isn't in the standard library.  A lot of basic functions/commands are defined in that library.  I say it's fine to use it at first because for beginners the double colons can be daunting, and it can be confusing.  I don't see why it was worth a downvote though, considering I did answer your question vividly.

Comment: >The double colons can be daunting.   
I would disagree with this statement. It is daunting because it isn't taught correctly and it is disgraceful from any practice. Simply adding `std::` to something from the standard library isn't daunting when it is taught correctly. For example, you say, It's okay to use `using namespace std;` without explaining what it does, where it comes from, or why it is used. I did not know what `using namespace std;` did until my second year of school. Bad habits are hard to break once started. @Thomas

Comment: >It's okay to use using namespace std; without explaining what it does, where it comes from, or why it is used  --- I would say then teachers just need to stop being vague on what it means, and explain what it means.  You can't explain the harder parts of a language until you get the fundamentals down.  Trust me, I am not too much of a fan of just telling your students to basically: "Copy this."  But when it comes to the beginning, it does make it somewhat easier for beginners to learn, in my opinion.